# Correspondence between influxdb runtime measurement statistics and Resident Memory(RES)

Tags: go, memory, influxdb

- Version: 1.8.10
- OS: CentOS 7
- Problem

  - According to the [document](https://docs.influxdata.com/platform/monitoring/influxdata-platform/tools/measurements-internal/#runtime), the "Sys" of the _internal database is: The total number of bytes of memory obtained from the OS. Measures the virtual address space reserved by the Go runtime for the heap, stacks, and other internal data structures.
  - But "Sys" or other statistics not equal with the Resident Memory(RES)(Following PID 9450)
  - What is the relationship between runtime statistics and RES
- Runtime
  [image: runtime statistics]
- RES-infuxd
  [image: RES-influxd]

known about the infuxdb runtime

Comment: I known now. "Sys" mean VIRT not RES. We can use the cmd "pmap -x  9450 | less" to see the RES of influxd proccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sys" mean VIRT not RES. We can use the cmd "pmap -x 9450 | less" to see the RES of influxd proccess